# If a point is not isolated then it is a limit point

Tags: general-topology

Let $k \in X$, where $X$ is a metric space.  I want to show that, if $k$ is not an isolated point of $U$ where $U \subseteq  X$, then it is a limit point of $u$ if $\exists u_{n} \in U$ whose elements are distinct s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}u_{n} = k$.

It seems fairly straightforwards verbally but I was not sure how to prove it. If $k$ is not an isolated point then that means when we consider a neighborhood around it $k$, the neighborhood will be in $U$ in some sort of way. Otherwise if $k$ was an isolated point then $k \cap U = \emptyset$. And then the result would follow. I know my idea was vague. I was just throwing out ideas. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of space is $X$? I assume $k \in U$. Could you please write the question as stated, and then I can help.

Comment: Are you working in a metric space?

Comment: Pelto I have edited my question. Sorry for not having enough details.

Comment: You want to show that "if A, then B if C"? What exactly does this double-if mean? Please edit to clarify. Also, you may want to state the definitions more precisely, without "some sort of way".

Comment: For future viewers of this post its worth noting: Given $U \subset X$ and $x \in U$. One can say equivalently that an element $x$ of $U$ is an isolated point of $U$ if and only if it is *not* a limit point of $U$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be a non-empty set in a metric space $(X,d)$, and let $p_o \in U$.

Suppose $p_o$ is not an isolated point of $U$. Then there does not exist $r>0$ so that 
\begin{equation}B(p_o,r) \cap U = \{p_o\} \,.
\end{equation}

In other words, for any $r > 0$ the open ball $B(p_o,r)$ must contain a point $p$ of $U$ which is distinct from $p_o$. Hence $p_o$ is a limit point of $U$ by definition.

Let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer. Since $1/n>0$, the open ball $B(p_o,1/n)$ contains a point of $U$ distinct from $p_o$ and we denote this point by $p_n$.

It now follows that for each positive integer $n$, there is a point $p_n \in U$ with $p_n \neq p_o$ and such that $d(p_n, p_o)<1/n$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By the Archimedean property, there is a positive integer $N$ so that $N\varepsilon>1$. It now follows that $d(p_n,p_o)<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. Thus we have shown that there is a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset U$ with $p_n \neq p_o$ for every $n$ and such that $p_n \to p_o$ as $n \to \infty$.